# Parallelism with tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, random-forest, decision-tree

I am trying to parallelize the growth of trees in random forest with my own implementation of a decision tree but parallelizing through tensorflow by building a parallel graph. Does `tf.map_fn` automatically execute the function on each subset of the tensor parallely?

say

```
tf.map_fn(lambda index: model.fit(xTrain[index,:],yTrain[index,:]).predict(xTest),partitions)
```

Here partitions is a list of row indices eg: `[[1,2,3],[2,3,4]]`

Also the function has an argument `parallel_iterations`:

The number of iterations allowed to run in parallel. When graph building, the default value is 10. While executing eagerly, the default value is set to 1

Does the argument mean how many subsets to run in parallel?

The system I am using has 48 cores and I basically want to exploit all the cores while building the forest.